# Categorizing string based on input in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, input, categories

Title is like tl;dr version, here is what I mean:

I made currently just a string (to be a file with text), and I am splitting this string into separate words. I would like to make a method that allows me to mark words based on string/file. For example:

```
string nameOfString = "John likes pancakes";
```

`Categorize(string nameOfString, class nameOfCategory)`

this method would make John, likes and pancakes into a category (like Stupid, bestTexts) I passed to nameOfCategory.
I would like to count then the words into all of the categorys, so probably should use some kind of array top do this. Can someone help me with this? The big problem is I really have no idea how to pass the category (as a seperate class or just a string, maybe string[]?) and still be able to count it.

Comment: Do you know how many categories you will have?

Comment: @MVCDS Number of categories will be probably two (2).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am currently reading about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but idk if this will help me in any way.

Comment: Strings will give you more flexibility if you want to expand categories, I'd group them in a dictionary of strings which values are list os strings (Dictionary<string, List<string>>), so I can count how many items are in the list of each string - a simple way that don't make you depend on new classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{ 
    var inputList = new List<string>
    {
        "John likes pancakes",
        "John hates watching TV",
        "I like my TV",
    };

    var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    inputList.ForEach(str => AddToDictionary(dic, str));

    foreach (var entry in dic)
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + ": " + entry.Value);
}

static void AddToDictionary(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary, string input)
{
    input.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(n =>
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(n))
            dictionary[n]++;
        else
            dictionary.Add(n, 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answear, I am new to c# and didn't know Dictoriany thingy :) Thanks, to the documentation! One more question tho, this looks like a counter to me (didn't build it yet, not on pc) - is there any method allowing me to add them to separate categories or should i just try with a "if x then y"?

Comment: You can make a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. If the dictionary `ContainsKey(n)` where `n` now is the name of your category, you do nothing. Else, you add a new category to your dictionary. Then in the main function, in the `foreach` loop, you can replace `entry.Value` with `entry.Count` to display the number of strings in each category. This is because `entry` is now a `List<string>` and not a `string`. Anyway, it's some variation of this. You should be able to tweak it to your needs. Do ask for help if needed :)

Comment: Hm, is "n" the category or a "word" (say TV, John)? In my understanding it is a word, am I wrong?

Comment: In my original answer, `input` is a string which is then splited into a list of strings. The `ForEach` extension method does the `if-else` stuff for each element from this list of strings. An element from this list of strings is represented by `n`. You can choose whatever name you want, not only `n`, and it will behave exactly the same. Check out [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Last thing: is there a way to use labda like this? `inputList.ForEach(str => AddToDictionary(dic, str) && str => AddToDictionary(dic2, string));`

Comment: Yes, but like this: `str => { AddToDictionary(dic, str);  AddToDictionary(dic2, string); }`. Everything after the `str =>` is the body of a function. So you can have code like in a normal function. And the `str` before de `=>` is the function parameter. So you have a function, with one parameter, and then you can have anything you would normally have in a normal function.